# How to create a stored procedure on SQL server 2014 for create table operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and and facing a problem In creating stored procedure. Can anybody tell me how I create a stored procedure for create table operation?

Comment: I just want to clarify, do you want to create a Stored Procedure (SP) and within the SP, create a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example of this store procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreatetable
AS
BEGIN
 Declare @createtablestr varchar(max)
  set @createtablestr ='CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
) '
excute @createtablestr ;
END
```